# Why is my list not updating outside the function? Aren't python lists called by assignment when passed in a function?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm not able to pass a lot of testcases for [this problem](https://leetcode.com/problems/remove-duplicates-from-sorted-array/). I ran the function as well as the code that the judge will use to test the function on my local machine and found out that the problem is that `nums` is not updated outside the function `removeDuplicates()` when it is is being called but it is updating within the function. Why is that? Aren't python lists called by assignment when passed in a function?

```
def removeDuplicates(nums):
    nums_ = set(nums)
    nums = []
    for i in nums_:
        nums.append(i)
    print(nums)
    # not working even if I do nums = list(set(nums)) instead of all lines above
    return len(nums)

nums = [1,1,2]
expectedNums = [1,2]

k = removeDuplicates(nums)
if k != len(expectedNums):
    print(False)
for i in range(k):
    if nums[i] != expectedNums[i]:
        print(False)
        print(nums, expectedNums)
        break
```

> **Output:**
>
> False
> [1, 1, 2]
>
> [1, 2]

Earlier I had used `nums = list(set(nums))` instead of emptying the list and appending all unique elements but even that wasn't working.

Comment: you do `nums = []`, so now `nums` is referring to another list.

Comment: so forget about a function. Consider; `x = [1, 2, 3]; y = x; print(x, y); x = []; print(x, y)` is what is going on

Comment: As an aside, to make the list unique, one would likely do a one-liner: `nums[:] = set(nums)`. And remember that sets can change order so your item by item comparison to expectedNums could fail even if they both have the same numbers (but in different order).

Comment: @tdelaney since the original `nums` was in non-decreasing order, I did `nums[:] = sorted(set(nums))` and it works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The line:

```
    nums = []
```

rebinds the local variable `nums` so that it no longer points to the list that was originally passed in, but to a newly created list.

If you instead do:

```
    nums.clear()
```

then you're mutating the original list instead of creating a new one.

Just remember that the `=` operator rebinds a variable, rather than modifying the object that the variable refers to.

[Obligatory Ned Batchelder link.](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html)

Note that a `[] =` subscript assignment also allows you to mutate a list (because you aren't assigning a value to the variable, you're assigning a value to an index or slice within the object that the variable refers to).  You could write your function very simply as:

```
def removeDuplicates(nums):
    nums[:] = set(nums)  # you can slice-assign into a list from a set!
    print(nums)
    return len(nums)
```

Comment: `nums = list(set(nums))` would also provide the deduplication functionality, although that won't work inside a separate function, for the parameter-reassignment reasons you mention

Comment: @SarahMesser  That's the exact thing that OP tried, and it didn't work (at least not in the way they intended) for the reasons described in this answer.